# Program doesn't print "Incorrect username or password" when writing them wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication

I'm doing a working login register program, which will write a `.txt` file and then confirm it to get logged in. The problem is that if I write my username and password, it doesn't print "Incorrect username or password" command if the username is wrong, it just shuts down.

```
print("Hello")
user = input("Do you have an account? y/n: ")
from getpass import getpass

#Function if you dont have an account
if user == "n":
    while True:
        username = input("Enter a username: ")
        password = input("Enter a password: ")
        password1 = input("Confirm your password: ")
        if password == password1:
            file = open(username+".txt", "w")
            file.write(username+":"+password)
            file.close()
            user = "y"
            break
        print("Passwords do NOT match")

#Function if you have an account
if user == "y":
    while True:
        username = input("Login: ")
        password = getpass("Password: ")
        file = open(username+".txt", "r")
        data = file.readline()
        file.close()
        if data == username+":"+password:
            print("Welcome", username)
            input("Press Enter to continue")
            break
        print("Incorrect username or password")
```

Comment: What is `getpass`? Importing that suggests that you might have some more complex authentication system, but your code relies on plain-text passwords being stored in a text file.

Comment: @roganjosh, `file.readline()` reads one line and it's not returning a list. I think the problem is with trailing newline character in `data`.

Comment: This is because your filename is `username.txt`. So if you enter wrong username, it gives error `FileNotFoundError`. But it works expected, if you write correct username with wrong password, it gives `Incorrect username or password`

Comment: It doesn't 'shut down', it throws a `FileNotFoundError`, as there is no file matching this username.

Comment: @Austin It's now twice I have made that mistake :/ You're possibly correct with the newline

Comment: @roganjosh Before you ask what is `getpass`, maybe you should first google it, or just try to import it in your python first :)

Comment: @roganjosh Isn't that the norm on SO? :) I think there's no need to mention it if it's irrelevant to the question, and everyone of us know that this is not going to be any production code.

Comment: @roganjosh The OP used `password = getpass("Password: ")`, and it's consistent with the assumption that they are importing the builtin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment: This is because your filename is `username.txt`. So if you enter wrong username, it gives error `FileNotFoundError`. But it works expected, if you write correct username with wrong password, it gives `Incorrect username or password`. So you need to make a file say `pass.txt`, and use this for reading and writing.

```
user = input("Do you have an account? y/n: ")
from getpass import getpass

filename = 'pass.txt'
#Function if you dont have an account
if user == "n":
    while True:
        username = input("Enter a username: ")
        password = input("Enter a password: ")
        password1 = input("Confirm your password: ")
        if password == password1:
            file = open(filename, "a")
            file.write(username+":"+password)
            file.write("\n")
            file.close()
            user = "y"
            break
        print("Passwords do NOT match")

#Function if you have an account
if user == "y":
    d = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        d = dict([line.rstrip().split(':') for line in f])
    while True:
        username = input("Login: ")
        password = getpass("Password: ")

        if (username in d and d[username] == password):
            print("Welcome", username)
            input("Press Enter to continue")
            break
        print("Incorrect username or password")
```

Comment: Still not quite right... I assume you want to *append* to the file in the first part?

Comment: @ImperishableNight: Oh yeah! I have done changes in pass file manually and tested for `user==y` block. Modified, thanks for pointing